# Can I adapt strings and built-in types in Z

Tags: adapter, zope, zope.interface

I have an Interface like:

```
class IRepository(Interface):
    def __init__(path, **options):
        pass
```

I have implementations of this interface for both Git, and Mercurial. Now I want to write repository-factory that takes a string (the path) and returns an IRepository, by probing if it's a `git` or `hg` repository.

However, simply saying:

```
registerAdapter(repofactory, (str, unicode, ), IRepository)
```

does not work, cause neither `str` nor `unicode` support the `IInterface` interface.

For now, I'm going with:

```
registerAdapter(repofactory, (Interface, ), IRepository)
```

But I would like to know if there are interfaces out there that match only string objects and other Python built-in types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, string and unicode objects can't have interfaces. But for this use-case, I'd register named utilities instead and look up the utility by name, or list all utilities available:

```
from zope.component import getUtilitiesFor, getUtility

names = [name for name, utility in getUtilitiesFor(IRepository)]

gitrepo = getUtility(IRepository, name='git')
```

Comment: Not exactly a solution, since the string is path in the fs and I would like to have an adapter that probes.